# How to make timed dialog that waits for response for max 30 seconds?

Tags: c#, dialog

I am trying to wrap my head around threading in C# but I am having difficulty implementing this behavior.

I need a simple yes/no dialog that returns `DialogResult.No` when 30 seconds are passed.

What I've got so far is this:

```
Thread th = new Thread(() =>
{
    try
    {
        result = message.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
});
th.Start();
Thread.Sleep(30000);
th.Abort();
```

When I select Yes or No on the dialog it still waits out the 30 seconds, I need the thread to stop when response is received.

This is probably a no brainer but I'm relatively new to C# and could really use some help on this.

Comment: You'll have to create your own Dialog control. The timing should be handled from within, and not via threads. Try using a Timer.

Comment: Which presentation technology are you using? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Timer when you initialize your Form.
When the timer expired, you close your Form.

```
Timer time1 = new Timer();
time1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
time1.Interval = 30000; // 30 secs
...
time1.Enabled = true; // Start the timer
message.ShowDialog();

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Close your Form
    message.Close();
    // Maybe you could set a variable, that indicates you, that the timer timed out

}
```

Comment: I understand now, should have looked at Timer instead of using Thread

Answer (score 0):

You have to overwrite `ShowDialog()` and `ShowDialog(owner)`. When your show dialog will be called you start a timer and forward to the `base.ShowDialog()`. When the timer raises the tick event simply call `Close()`.

Here an example implementation:

```
public partial class FormTimed : Form
{
    private String _OriginalText;
    private DateTime _StartTime;
    private Timer _Timer;

    public FormTimed()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeTimer();

        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(TimeSpan), "00:00:10")]
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _OriginalText;
        }
        set
        {
            _OriginalText = value;
            base.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public void DisableTimer()
    {
        _Timer.Stop();
        base.Text = _OriginalText;
    }

    public void ResetTimer()
    {
        _StartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        _Timer.Start();
    }

    public new DialogResult ShowDialog()
    {
        StartTimer();
        return base.ShowDialog();
    }

    public new DialogResult ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
    {
        StartTimer();
        return base.ShowDialog(owner);
    }

    private void InitializeTimer()
    {
        _Timer = new Timer();
        _Timer.Interval = 100;
        _Timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
    }

    private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var finishTime = _StartTime + Duration;
        var remainingDuration = finishTime - DateTime.UtcNow;

        if (remainingDuration < TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            Close();
        }

        base.Text = _OriginalText + " (" + (int)remainingDuration.TotalSeconds + ")";
    }

    private void StartTimer()
    {
        _StartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        _Timer.Start();
    }
}
```